# Device back button code is not working when i open camera in android device in cordova app

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

This is the code to handle back button in cordova app, but it fails when i open camera to scan, back button code it not working from camera screen, any help would be appreciated.

```js
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);  
function onBackKeyDown(e) { 
   e.preventDefault(); 
   alert('Back Button is Pressed!'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are on the camera or the scan screen, those are native screens launched from an Intent. When you are on an Intent screen, your app code doesn't work. What you want to do is not possible.